# Avoiding many if statements - different datatypes

Tags: java, if-statement

I have many `if` statements and I want to avoid them.

I tried with HashMap, but it did not work with datatypes. Please see the code below that I have. This is just the first `if` statement but I have more...
field is a DataType

```
   if (field.equals(DataTypes.IntegerType)) {
     x = Integer.valueOf();
    } 

    [...]
else if (field instanceof org.apache.spark.sql.types.TimestampType) {
  try {
    x = Timestamp.valueOf();
  } catch (Exception) {
    try {
      columns[i] = Timestamp.valueOf(...).toLocalDateTime());
    } catch (Exception) {

      throw new ParseException("...");
    }
  }
   [...]


    else {
    x = null
   }
```

Can I somehow avoid so many else `if` statements?

Comment: What type does `field` have? Where is the final `else`?

Comment: You can avoid the use of `if (type == foo) foo.doSomething()` by using interfaces and polymorphism. [This example](https://refactoring.guru/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism) should give you some inspiration. But remember, sometimes it's fine to have plenty of if/else, there is no hard rule about which pattern to use.

Comment: As you might have guessed: in order to write better code, we have to understand what DataTypes "is": So we need more context.

Comment: field is a DataType from a schema-field.

Comment: else column[i] = null

Comment: A `switch` statement will not give you fewer lines but it is usually easier to read

Comment: Is `DataTypes` your enum, can you change it? Also, is `else` really possible? Or there more `DataTypes` values than checked here?

Comment: if I do it with switch, it does not take my variable 'field' in switch (field)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep a static Map of the conversions:

```
private static final Map<DataType, Function<String, ?>> stringConverters;

static {
    Map<DataType, Function<String, ?>> map = new EnumMap<>(DataType.class);

    map.put(DataType.IntegerType,   Integer::valueOf);
    map.put(DataType.LongType,      Long::valueOf);
    map.put(DataType.DoubleType,    Double::valueOf);
    map.put(DataType.FloatType,     Float::valueOf);
    map.put(DataType.StringType,    Function.identity());
    map.put(DataType.BinaryType,    Binary::fromString);

    if (!map.keySet().containsAll(EnumSet.allOf(DataType.class))) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
            "Programming error: Not all DataType values accounted for.");
    }

    stringConverters = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}

// ...

    columns[i] = stringConverters.get(field).apply(s);
```

The `containsAll` check is useful for making sure you don’t overlook any of the DataType values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does it also work with map.put if I have something like else if (field instance of ....) and then in the brackets try and catch statement?

Comment: It might, depending on what you’re doing in that try/catch.

Comment: you can see an update... this is an example from my code with try-catch statement

Comment: In light of your additional code, it appears that the type of `field` is Object, and it can hold either a `DataType` or a `TimestampType`.  Is that correct?

Comment: yeess.. so it is a DataType and it can be IntegerType, LongType, ... and so on and it can also be a TimestampType and then I have also to check if it is a DateType... It can be any type. -> therefore, the if statements

Comment: It seems like it would be easier to add a DataType.TimestampType constant, and declare `field` to be of type `DataType`.  That certainly would make it easier to adopt my Map suggestion.

Comment: field is already declared as DataType:
DataType field = schema.fields()[i].dataType()

Comment: Then `if (field instanceof org.apache.spark.sql.types.TimestampType)` will always be false, won’t it?

Comment: How can a DataType constant be an instance of TimestampType?

Comment: with 'instanceof', you check if an object is an instance of a specific class. You normally use it, when you have a reference or parameter to an object that is of a super class or interface type and need to know whether the actual object has some other type.

Comment: And if the type of `field` is an enum type, its value *must* be one of the constants in that enum type (or null).  It *cannot* be a `org.apache.spark.sql.types.TimestampType` value.  Java is a typesafe language.

Answer (score 1):

I assume DataTypes is an enum.
The simplest method would require access to the DataTypes enum to add a method that is implemented by each type.

```
enum DataTypes {
    IntegerType() {
        public Object valueFrom(String s) {
            return Integer.parseInt(s);
        }
    },
    LongType() {
        return Long.parseLong(s);
    }; // CONTINUE WITH ALL TYPES

    public Object valueFrom(String s) {
        return s;
    }
}
```

Then you would simplify that code to:

```
columns[i] = field.valueFrom(s);
```

You could also keep the convert methods separated and just have a field in each enum type that holds a reference to the converter method for that type:

```
enum DataTypes {
    IntegerType(Integer::parseInt),
    LongType(Long::parseLong); // CONTINUE WITH ALL TYPES

    private Function<String,Object> converter;

    DataTypes(Function<String,Object> converter) {
        this.converter = converter;
    }

    public Object valueFrom(String s) {
        return converter.apply(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: DataTypes comes from import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes

Comment: Ah, in that case I would go with VGR's answer.

Answer (score -4):

you can use switch but still if/else is preferred over any other method.

Comment: "if/else is preferred over any other method" says who?

Comment: Could you please elaborate why *`if`/`else` is preferred over any other method*?

Comment: for one or two values, there's nothing wrong with if-else, but for multiple values a switch block 'll make the whole part o lot easier to read

Comment: If-else conditional branches are great for variable conditions

Comment: @AakashdeepSingh what do you mean by "variable conditions"?

Comment: @Aakashdeep Singh Except the condition in this example is a consequence of the goal, which is to use the correct conversion for the Type.  It is not a condition that is used for the _logic_ of the code itself, there are definitely ways to refactor this properly.

Comment: @AakashdeepSingh and you mean to say a switch case construct is not?

Comment: if I do it with switch, it does not take my variable 'field' in switch (field)... and says that I should use if statement